# Is it useful to tag closed questions with the [recipe] tag?

Tags: discussion, retagging

I saw [this](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/why-is-there-a-recipe-tag) question on meta. I see the use in it if the question is still open. But what with recipe asking questions that are already closed?

I was about to tag [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20713/cookie-recipe-without-milk) question, when I hesitated. I think it would be useful (perhaps to have an overview for the all the recipe questions), but if the purpose is to delete all the closed questions eventually, there is no use of tagging these questions after they are closed.

So what do the mods want the humble users to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't retag closed questions unless you reasonably expect that they will be reopened, or at least remain on the site without deletion. A retag counts as an edit for the purpose of bumping the question to the front page, and we want to avoid promoting crap unnecessarily.

The vast majority of recipe requests are eventually deleted. In theory, if we had a lot of users with sufficient rep, the community would delete them within a few days; in practice, for the time being, poor/off-topic questions tend to get deleted whenever one or more of the moderators decides to do a sweep of old closed questions, which is probably once every few months.

Either way, they're on their way to deletion, and don't need/deserve any extra attention.