# Meta tags need blacklisting

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We have recently had two meta tags (re?)appear, and grow in popularity. The first is the [cooking] tag, the second is the [recipe] tag.

Since these tags should be applicable to basically 100% of our questions, I submit a request for blacklisting.

Comment: Looks like there's still a bunch of questions with those tags. Seems like [tag:cooking] should indeed be an intrinsic tag; is there community consensus that [tag:recipe] should also be considered intrinsic? I'd recommend going through the process described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/208518) before escalating it to the CM team. I'll remove [meta-tag:status-review] for now, but please add it in once you've gone through that process ^_^

Comment: @JNat thank you for taking a look. I don't know about other opinions within the community about the recipe tag, for me it fails the usual tests of a tag. First, I would say that about 90% of our questions are connected to a recipe, giving it no distinguishing power. Second, if you look at the questions where it is used, it is not necessarily questions where the recipe is somehow in focus. Third, it doesn't create an area of expertise - there are no cooks who specialize in "recipes". Fourth, it becomes more difficult for new people to believe that the site forbids recipe requests when they...

Comment: ... find a tag which, in their mind, fits their desire ("I want a recipe") perfectly. I will still ask in chat if somebody wants to write an answer for or against the arguments for removing the recipe tag, maybe there will be some activity.

Comment: Those sound like good arguments to remove the tags — I'd be fine with moving ahead with this sans the discussion, but have a look through the post for the other cleanup steps that should be taken before the tag gets blocked ;)

Comment: @JNat I cleaned up the two tags manually, there are now no questions with them.

Comment: Definitely agree on cooking needing to be an intrinsic tag. Looks like aaronut had a reasoning for keeping the recipe tag around - https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/why-is-there-a-recipe-tag/1315#1315 What do y'all think about this - I'm not personally a huge fan of the "we'll have an easy way to find questions that should be closed" argument at this point. Particularly since y'all don't get enough QPD that finding these new ones is that difficult. Thoughts?

Comment: @Catija interesting, I had forgotten that one! He says "Please do get rid of the recipe tag for questions that are actually salvageable; for questions that are in fact recipe requests, just vote to close" and I did that for all questions which had the tag, so right now, we can remove it from the system once and for all, before it gets used again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All set. Going forward, [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) will be blocked as intrinsic and [recipe](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recipe) will be blocked all around.